# How PHP knows the encoding of the .php files?

Tags: php, encoding, interpreter

How does PHP know the encoding of the .php-files it interprets?

I mean the .php-files could be encoded in e.g. UTF-8 or CP 1252. And this would affect e.g. string literals.

Is there one setting in the php.ini? Or does PHP try to determine the encoding automatically (e.g. assume CP 1252 if no valid UTF-8 ...)?

Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: it only depends on your editor, not on php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP source code makes no assumption about the source encoding. Everything is treated as binary. This means that if your editor saves a file as CP-1252 (I sure hope not), the strings you echo are also CP-1252.

Comment: And every string-operation is done with iso-8859-1 encoding. You'll have to use mbstring or iconv for any encoding which is different to iso-8859-1.

Comment: Every string operation is by default done single-byte, but safe for a few default ini settings & function arguments, PHP doesn't care about which single-byte character set.

Comment: So I should always use `mb_*` string functions and never again e.g. `strlen`? (If my web app is completly UTF-8)

Comment: Quite frankly, In reality I personally do a ton of string manipulation, but not a crazy amount of that requires mbstring. Most of it is for example juggling with urls and identifiers. So yes: anything that's actual text in UTF-8 you should use mbstring.

Comment: There's such a thing as mbstring function overloading, but avoid this at all cost!

Answer (score 2):

The encoding of a file has very little to do with string literals in it. Strings are just a sequence of bytes as far as PHP is concerned, no further data is stored. If you include utf-8 strings in a iso-8859-15 file, it will still be the bytes of an utf-8 string. As these are just bytes, you are free to mix different encodings in strings in the same file (although they would look weird in any editor).

You are probably not looking to define an encoding of a file, but just how to handle & output strings. You can define what it outputs as a header (which is most likely what you want) with the `default_charset` ini-setting, and internal `mb_` functions listen to `mbstring.internal_encoding`.

Note that `zend.multibyte` should be able to actually scan files in a different encoding which are not compatible with the normal scanner (for instance CP936, Big5, CP949, Shift_JIS), which you can configure in ini settings & help with a `declare(encoding='name')`, but I very much doubt this is what you are looking for. I have yet to test that functionality, and the documentation of it is next no non-existent.

Comment: _"The encoding of a file has very little to do with string literals in it."_ - I think you want to put this in a different way. The encoding of a file **is** about how textual data in it is stored. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding): _"A character encoding [...] pairs each character from a given repertoire with something else—such as a bit pattern [...] to facilitate [...] data storage."_

Comment: @CodeCaster: Hm, might be a bit obscure what I mean indeed: It may matter for the _document_ but NOT for PHP's interpretation of it: the string literals are interpreted as a sequence of bytes, so you _can_ use different encodings for your string literals as much as you like in 1 single file. PHP strings don't _have_ an encoding, they are just bytes.